# Creating a new spreadsheet with default row and column values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a Google spreadsheet with default row and column values. I know how to create spreadsheet with desired title, default format, etc. but don't know how to populate it with desired data.

What I've so far:

```
function makeApiCall() {
      var spreadsheetBody = {
        // TODO: Add desired properties to the request body.
        "properties": {
    "title": "Created from localhost"
  },

      };

      var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.create({}, spreadsheetBody);
      request.then(function(response) {

        console.log(response.result);
      }, function(reason) {
        console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
      });
    }
```

I've referred the API docs and there seems to be no information regarding creating a spreadsheet by populating it with default values.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%7D%7D

Comment: You could create the Spreadsheet from a copy of another which has all the headers and proper formatting you want.  You can add values with range.setValues or sheet.appendRow() or any of the many copy commands.  Read the reference section of the documenation it's all in there.

Comment: You want to achieve your goal using Javascript which is not Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

### If your goal is to set values to a spreadsheet with the Sheets API in Javascript:

After you create the spreadsheet, you can retrieve its ID and use the method [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) to add sheets and contents as desired with the [requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request) "addSheet" and "pasteData".

> Sample request:

```
var myData="1,2,3,, ,4";
var request={requests: [
              { 
               pasteData: {
                data: myData,
                type: "PASTE_NORMAL",
                delimiter: ",",
                coordinate: {
                  sheetId: 0,
                  rowIndex: 0,
                  }
                }
              }
           ]
        };
```

> Sample batchUpdate from the documentation:

```
    function makeApiCall() {
      var params = {
        // The spreadsheet to apply the updates to.
        spreadsheetId: 'my-spreadsheet-id',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.
      };

      var batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequestBody = {
        // A list of updates to apply to the spreadsheet.
        // Requests will be applied in the order they are specified.
        // If any request is not valid, no requests will be applied.
        requests: request,  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        // TODO: Add desired properties to the request body.
      };

      var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(params, batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequestBody);
      request.then(function(response) {
        // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
        console.log(response.result);
      }, function(reason) {
        console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
      });
    }
```